# JUnit test for specific file restricts giving false output

Tags: java, regex

I had requirement where user should add only specific type of links
as part of the attachments. For example, if user wants to upload
file of type pdf, the url should end with .pdf similarly for document
it should be .doc

To check this scenario I had written JUnit test as below

```
String url="ar.jpg";
String pm="(.*?)\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("pm");
Matcher m = p.matcher(url);     
System.out.println("-----exp  "+m.matches());
```

This test is always returning false.

Is there something wrong
with my Pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a misprint - **"pm" string** is passed to compile() method, but **pm variable** must be passed:

```
String pm="(.*?)\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pm); // <- here
```

Comment: Good catch..Is there anything to be modified as far as string pm is conserned.I mean...does it fits into any kind of URl which ends with jpg,jpeg etc..

Comment: I don't see any problems in regexp itself - it should work for all strings which end with ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png", ".gif".

Comment: Can I know what is the exact file extension here using another regular expression.

Comment: You can do it, for example, in the following way: String[] urlArray = url.split("\."); String extension = urlArray[urlArray.length - 1];

Comment: Also, you may take a look at Matcher.group() function (http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group()) - it returns matched substring. In this case you will need regexp, which includes only extension check.